# Saved image data to core data but launches simulator again, it's gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage

I have saved image data to core data, the key is binary data format. After I saved to the core data, I displaying the image in a UIImageView using valueForKey: . But After I launch the simulator again, everything is still saved, but the image data is gone, when I NSLog the key's data description, it's null.

```
NSDictionary *show = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
Summary *summary = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Summary" inManagedObjectContext:weakSelf.managedObjectContext];
summary.title = show[@"title"];
summary.poster = show[@"images"][@"poster"];

SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:summary.poster] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    summary.posterImageData = data;
}];

[weakSelf.managedObjectContext dct_saveWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your current code, the downloadWithURL's completed block is being called after dct_saveWithCompletionHandler , try:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:summary.poster] options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {

} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
    summary.posterImageData = data;
    [weakSelf.managedObjectContext dct_saveWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];    
}];
```

Comment: If the save not success,I won't be able to create a fetch request and get the results back?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're actually saving the managed object context. Doublecheck that you've set the concurrency type for your MOCs correctly, too.

Comment: I saved the context and then create a fetch request to get the results back. Doesn't it mean I have already saved the context. If not, how to make sure of that?